# Recompile Query-Hint on a System.Data.Linq.DataContext object

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have a query that is being called by a DataContext object that is creating an extremely inefficient execution plan. I would like to add an "OPTION(RECOMPILE)" query hint to the query, but I do not know how to add this query hint to a DataContext object's query.

I ran a SQL trace in order to capture the query. I ran it manually as is and it took almost four minutes, by adding "OPTION(RECOMPILE)" to the query it reduced the run time to a second. The query contains many variables, a couple table-value functions and a view with an embedded table-value function. All the input variables are numbers. The query plans between the two executions were very different.

I do not need help optimizing the code to avoid the poor execution plan; I can do this myself if I need to go this route. All I need to know is if there is a way to add the OPTION(RECOMPILE) query hint to my Linq query. I'm not going to post the code, it is irrelevant to my question.

If it's possible to add the Recompile Query-Hint please let me know how and if it is not possible if you could please provide a link to some documentation that indicates this to be the case I would appreciate it.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 as my rdbms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270490/entity-framework-4-2-exec-sp-executesql-does-not-use-indexes-parameter-sniffing.  You may get some help there.

Comment: Sir, i faced same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I've ready some posts where they wrote something to intercept the query on its way to the database to be executed and modified it to add a query hint, but I also read responses where people said it didn't work for them. I would suggest going a different route and just managing the SQL logic yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue against EF requesting that hints are added in future - http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/261.

If you're lucky it would make it into EF 6.