# Stored procedure is not using indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, indexing

This stored procedure is the result of a linq query execution: I got it from the Sql Server Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[object] AS [object], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (50) 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [object], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[object] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[BEM_EVT_FULL] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[date] > @p__linq__0
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[object]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2015-01-21 00:00:00'
```

I have created indexes on all the columns (object and date). The problem is that this query is totaly ignoring indexes and takes more than 3 minutes to run.

On the other hand I have this query that I've run manually.

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[object] AS [object], 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (50) 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [object], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[object] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[BEM_EVT_FULL] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[date] > convert(datetime2, '2015-01-21 00:00:00.0000000', 121)
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[object]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
)  AS [Limit1]
```

This query benefits from indexes and run under 1s. Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Comment: have you proved this by looking at the plan? and is the timing from SQL profiler or your .NET code?

Comment: Parameter sniffing? Check the plan and see what value it was compiled with (properties of the first thing on the left)

Comment: How do you know it is ignoring the indexes? If it is just execution time I agree with @JamesZ that this is likely a case of parameter sniffing.

Comment: As an aside, [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9270490/61305).

Comment: @SteveDrake i've proved this by looking at sql server profiler

Comment: @JamesZ how to check the plan

Comment: When it's running you can use something like this to get the plan: "SELECT qp.* FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) qp
WHERE session_id = XXX" where XXX is the spid / session id.

Comment: I have checked stored procedures in the DB there was none of them

Answer (score 0):

I feel like adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) will help you. The problem is how do you the Entity Framework to do that. Check out this link [Adding a query hint when calling Table-Valued Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761827/adding-a-query-hint-when-calling-tvf)

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C1], 
                [Limit1].[object] AS [object], 
                [Limit1].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (50) [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
                        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [object], 
                        1 AS [C2]
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
            [Extent1].[object] AS [K1], 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[BEM_EVT_FULL] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[date] > @p__linq__0
            GROUP BY [Extent1].[object]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Limit1]
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)',

    N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',
    @p__linq__0='2015-01-21 00:00:00'
```

Comment: The OP doesn't control the text of the query; it's generated by that icky Entity Framework thing [that doesn't do a very good job](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bindeshv/archive/2010/07/13/ef-query-execution-pattern-usage-of-sp-executesql-vs-direct-execution-of-sql-statement.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited my answer with a link to someone who managed to do it.

Comment: Ugh, that is ugly. I wonder if all the ugly workarounds and hacks you have to perform to make EF behave properly are worth any so-called advantages...

Comment: I think i'm having parameter sniffing issue, withe the dateTime passed in where statement

Comment: @Stephan are you sure we put OPTION(RECOMPILE) at that statement ?

Comment: I don't know. I thought you would run the script in my answer and see if it corrects your problem. Then if it works, I thought you would figure out how to add OPTION(RECOMPILE) to your entity script from the link I found.